# Push is deleting files created with fwrite

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

I am using a form to create webpages but each time I do a push it deletes those files. I know I need to put the files in a directory that is for persistent data but A) I do not know what directory and B) I do not know how to make sure the URL I create and put in the database is accessible to users when they click it. Here is my php code that creates the webpage from a form.

```
<?php 
$myContent = $_POST['mycontent'];
$titlestart = '<h1>';
$titlestop = '</h1>';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$appendtitle = 'kb'.$title;
$filename = preg_replace('/( *)/', '', $appendtitle);

$footer = file_get_contents('footer.html');
$myFile = $filename.".html";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = file_get_contents('template.html');
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fwrite($fh, $titlestart);
fwrite($fh, $title);
fwrite($fh, $titlestop);
fwrite($fh, $myContent);
fwrite($fh, $footer);
fclose($fh);

$dbhost = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST');
$dbname = getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME');
$dbuser = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME');
$dbpass = getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD');
$topicid = 'NULL';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$url = 'https://research-statusquopro.rhcloud.com/'.$filename.'.html';
$keyword = $_POST['keywords'];
$faq = $_POST['faq'];
$category= $_POST['category'];
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
if (empty($title))
{
}
else
{
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO topics (`topicid` ,`topictitle` ,`topicdescription` ,`url` ,`keyword`,`faq`,`Category`) VALUES ('".$topicid."','".$title."','".$description."','".$url."','".$keyword."','".$faq."',".$category."')");
header ('Location: https://urlofapplication');                                            

}
//mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openshift provides a persistent storage directory that you can access by using the $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR environment variable.

Comment: How do I add a symbolic link between the external facing (php folder) to the folder in the persistent storage?

Comment: The folder location on your app is `~/app-root/data` so a symlink to that should work.

Comment: would this work?
`$myContent = $_POST['mycontent'];`
`$titlestart = '<h1>';`
`$titlestop = '</h1>';`
`$title = $_POST['title'];`
`$appendtitle = 'kb'.$title;`
`$filename = preg_replace('/( *)/', '', $appendtitle);`
`$filepath = getenv('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR');`
`$myFile = $filepath."/".$filename.".html";`
`$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');`
`$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a')`
`$stringData = file_get_contents('template.html');
`fwrite($fh, $stringData);
`fwrite($fh, $titlestart);
`fwrite($fh, $title);`
`fwrite($fh, $titlestop);`
`fwrite($fh, $myContent);`
`fclose($fh);`